# Linear algebra explanation of general solution to the example

Tags: linear-algebra

I've just started studying a math book for machine learning called [Mathematics for Machine Learning](https://mml-book.com) and I've come across with the example below.

I've understood till the part where it says:

> Adding 0 to our special solution does not change the special
>   solution. To do so, we express the third column using the first two columns
>   (which are of this very simple form) 
>   $$\begin{bmatrix}8\\2\end{bmatrix} = 8 \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} + 2\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

But then I am lost. How did we find these coefficients in the equation below?

$$0 = 8c_1 + 2c_2 - 1c_3 + 0c_4$$

Then what did we do with the third column that we'd written in the form of $1^{st}$ and $2^{nd}$ column above?

*I couldn't post images since I do not have 10 reputation points so I am sharing the links to the images.*

[Linear algebra special and general solution example page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnvm1.png)

[Linear algebra special and general solution example page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sajnt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $c_i$ are the columns of the coefficient matrix.  $c_1=\pmatrix{1\\0},$ $c_2=\pmatrix{0\\1},$$c_3=\pmatrix{8\\2}=8c_1+2c_2.$  That is to say, $$8c_1+2c_2-c_3=0$$

Comment: Oh, now it makes sense. I was just thinking that we would substitute the 3rd column. Thank you!